# Intent не переносит на другой activity при верификации почты

Tags: java, android, firebase, activity, android-intent

```
package com.example.testapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText usernameReg;
    private EditText passwordReg;
    private Button buttonR;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseR;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        firebaseR = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        usernameReg = findViewById(R.id.editTextReg);
        passwordReg = findViewById(R.id.editTextReg1);
        buttonR = findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);



        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()) {
                    redirectToMainActivity4();
                }
            }
        };


        buttonR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (usernameReg.getText().toString().isEmpty() || passwordReg.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Fields cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    firebaseR.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usernameReg.getText().toString(), passwordReg.getText().toString())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        verifyEmail();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void redirectToMainActivity4() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity4.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private void verifyEmail() {
        assert usernameReg != null;
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseR.getCurrentUser();
        assert user != null;
        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "На вашу электронную почту отправлено письмо для верификации", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Ошибка: Письмо не отправлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что ваша переменная `authStateListener` живет не сильно дольше, чем выполняется метод `onCreate()`. Сделайте из нее поле класса.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `authStateListener` нигде не используется.
Этот слушатель нужно добавить в `onStart()` и удалить в `onStop()`.
Что-то вроде:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseR.addAuthStateListener(fireAuthListener);
    }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(fireAuthListener != null){
        firebaseR.removeAuthStateListener(fireAuthListener);
    }
}
```